# Blazor - class constructor injected variables always null?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm relatively new to Blazor and am writing a new server-side application. In order to allow the program to determine at start up which DBContextFactory to add (and which database to connect to), I've created a class to do all of the work. But when creating my class object, my contextFactory is always null (as well as my navManager) when I proceed to debug my code. Specifically, in this case, it's occurring in the GetDatabase() method. The nav manager is a requirement, as I need the BaseURI in order to confirm what site the user is accessing the application from, and therefore which database to use. I know that I'm overlooking something obvious but need some help figuring out where I've gone wrong.

Here is the applicable code for my Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
var dinfo = new Lookup();


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();

if (builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection").Contains("Lookup"))
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<NewLookupDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    var dServer = dinfo.LookupServer();
    var dDB = dinfo.LookupDatabase();
    cb.DataSource = dServer.Result.ServerName.ToString();
    cb.InitialCatalog = dDB.Result.DatabaseName.ToString();
    cb.UserID = dServer.Result.ServerUserID.ToString();
    cb.Password = dServer.Result.ServerPassword.ToString();
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<LookupDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    var vInfo = dinfo.GetDatabase();
    cb.DataSource = vInfo.Result.DBServer.ToString();
    cb.InitialCatalog = vInfo.Result.DBName.ToString();
    cb.UserID = vInfo.Result.DBUserName.ToString();
    cb.Password = vtInfo.Result.DBPassWord.ToString();
}
```

The relevant DBContext can be seen here, there's not much to them:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NewApp_Database.Data
{
    public class LookupDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public LookupDbContext(DbContextOptions<LookupDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public LookupDbContext()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Database> tblDB { get; set; }

    }

}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NewApp_Database.Data
{
    public class NewLookupDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public NewLookupDbContext(DbContextOptions<NewLookupDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public NewLookupDbContext()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<NewDatabase> Database { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NewServer> Server { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NewDomain> Domain { get; set; }


    }

}
```

And then finally, the applicable code for the Lookup class that I made:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace NewApp_Database.Data
{
    public class Lookup
    {
        public NavigationManager _navigationManager { get; set; }
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<NewLookupDbContext> _contextFactoryNew;
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<LookupDbContext> _contextFactory;

        public Lookup(NavigationManager navigationManager, IDbContextFactory<NewLookupDbContext> newContextFactory, IDbContextFactory<LookupDbContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
            _contextFactoryNew = newContextFactory;
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public Lookup()
        {

        }

        public async Task<NewDomain> LookupDomain()
        {
            var navDomain = _navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(_navigationManager.BaseUri).ToString().Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("/", "");
            if (navDomain != null)
            {
                await using var context = await _contextFactoryNew.CreateDbContextAsync();
                var obj = await context.Domain.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.DomainName == navDomain);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    return obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<NewDatabase>LookupDatabase()
        {
            var dDomain = LookupDomain();

            if (dDomain != null)
            {
                await using var context = await _contextFactoryNew.CreateDbContextAsync();
                var obj = await context.Database.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.DatabaseID == dDomain.Result.DatabaseID);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    return obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<NewServer> LookupServer()
        {
            var dDatabase = LookupDatabase();

            if (dDatabase != null)
            {
                await using var context = await _contextFactoryNew.CreateDbContextAsync();
                var obj = await context.Server.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ServerID == dDatabase.Result.ServerID);
                if (obj != null)
                {
                    return obj;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public async Task<Database> GetDatabase()
        {
            await using var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
            var obj = await context.tblDB.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.fOrder == 0);
            if (obj != null)
            {
                return obj;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many DbContexts are there.  Is this a one for debug, one for testing,...?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, there are two.

Comment: @HH My intention was actually to have one or the other, depending on which one is needed.

Comment: There is also no reason not to have two registered, and then choose which one you use at runtime.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - but then you need two interfaces too, and a lot of if/else code. When they are (mostly) interchangeable, I would have 1 interface.

Comment: @HH - maybe, but there are many ways to code this.  My guess here is *bm0102* is probably overcomplicating this, but without seeing everything and understanding the context it's hard to judge.